# Datepicker won't load Properly

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap-4, jquery-ui-datepicker

**Hi I'm working with project, I have a problem with bootstrap datepicker it's not displaying properly, I don't know what causing it maybe my scripts, but I tried to arrange the script depends on their versions but still won't work. Do I have a conflict on css? I'm stuck on this error. Please help me on this.**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" />

<!--<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">


    
@php
$users =App\Models\User::select('name','id')->where('email',Auth::user()->email)->get();
$getcurrentId = App\Models\User::select('id')->where('email',Auth::user()->email)->get();
$d = new DateTime();
$date = $d->format('Y-m-d');
$current_date = date('Y-m-d');
$infos= App\Models\User::all();
$empattendance= App\Models\Attendance::select('Name','CheckIn','CheckOut','Note','Date','TotalHours')->where('Date','=',$current_date)->get();
foreach($getcurrentId as $gId)
{
    $currentUser= App\Models\Attendance::orderBy('id','DESC')->select('id','Name','CheckIn','CheckOut','Note','Date','TotalHours')->where('user_id','=',$gId->id)->get();
}



@endphp
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" style="background-color:#007bff;">
                    <h3 class="card-title" style=" color:white;">

                Attendance</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-header -->
                <div class="card-body">
              
<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<div class="info">
<div class="row">

     
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empid"  name="name" style="display:none;">
  
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"  name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="name">Position</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="position"  name="position">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="name"></label>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary selectemp" style="margin-top:30px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">Select Employee</button>
    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="name">Date Start</label>
        <input class="date form-control"  type="text" id="datepickerstart" name="datepickerstart">
    
    </div>
</div>

<div class="btnbrowse">

</div>

<table class="table table-striped" id="admindatatable" style="margin:0 auto;">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <!--<th style="text-align : center;">ID</th>-->
                        <th style="text-align : center;">Name</th>
                        <th style="text-align : center;">Check In</th>
                        <th style="text-align : center;">Check Out</th>
                        <th style="text-align : center;">Note</th>
                        <th style="text-align : center;">Total</th>
                        <th style="text-align : center;">Date</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <!--<td style="text-align : center;" class="id"></td>-->
                        <td style="text-align : center;" class="id"></td>
                        <td style="text-align : center;" class="checkin"></td>
                        <td style="text-align : center;" class="checkout"></td>
                        <td style="text-align : center;" class="note"></td>
                        <td style="text-align : center;" class="note"></td>
                        <td style="text-align : center;" class="date"></td>
                    </tr>
                
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>

            <!-- /.card-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
        <!-- /.card -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
      </div>
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Check In</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
        Are you sure you want to Check In?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btnConfirmCheckIN">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmModalCheckOut" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Check Out</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
        Are you sure you want to Check Out?
            </div>-
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btnConfirmCheckOut">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Employee</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group">
     
     <table class="table" id="emplist" style="margin:0 auto;">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th style="display:none;">Position</th>
                        
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    @foreach ($infos as $info)
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td  class="id">{{ $info->id}}</td>
                        <td  class="emplistname">{{$info->name}}</td>
                        <td  class="emplistname" style="display:none;">{{$info->position}}</td>
                        
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
     
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnselect">Select</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-T/tUfKSV1bihCnd+MxKD0Hm1uBBroVYBOYSk1knyvQ9VyZJpc/ALb4P0r6ubwVPSGB2GvjeoMAJJImBG12TiaQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="" sha256-sefm2ay87nr5kce4f+rtmbkkxbqhec2uehgnptoa5xi="" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>-->




<script>
jQuery.browser = {};
(function () {
jQuery.browser.msie = false;
jQuery.browser.version = 0;
  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)\./)) {
    jQuery.browser.msie = true;
    jQuery.browser.version = RegExp.$1;
}})();

$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j('#datepickerstart').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
     });
    var date = new Date();
    var val=date.getFullYear()+"-"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"-"+date.getDate()

 
     $('.labelDate').text(val);
     //$("#datepicker").val(val);
     //alert("test");

     $j('#datatable').DataTable();
     $j('#admindatatable').DataTable();
     $j('#empdatatable').DataTable();
    $('.checkin').click(function(){
        var clock = $('#clock').text();
        var data = $('#userClock').val(clock);

    });

 $('.selectemp').click(function(){
   // $('#admindatatable').css("display","none");
 });

 $('.btntest').click(function(){

    //$('#admindatatable').css("display","block");
 });

 $('#emplist tr').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');

 });
var selectedrow;
$('#emplist tr').click(function(e) {
$('#emplist tr').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
selectedrow = $(this);

});

$('.btnselect').click(function(){

var td = selectedrow.children('td');
var id = td.eq(0).text();
var name = td.eq(1).text();
var pos =td.eq(2).text();
$('#name').val(name);
$('#position').val(pos);
$('#empid').val(id);
$("#exampleModalLong").modal().hide();
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();

});
});
</script>
```

[Please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVXb7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your input tag is not proper, edit it first.

From:

```
<input class="date form-control"  type="text" id="datepickerstart" 
name="datepickerstart">
```

To:

```
<input class="form-control"  type="date" id="datepickerstart" 
name="datepickerstart">
```

Hope this will be useful.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-md-12">
<label>Date</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the posted code, it seems you tried many things.

If you decide to use bootstrap datepicker, do not load jQuery-ui.

I suggest loading `bootstrap` CSS first... And then the plugins CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

About loading the JS, it is important to load jQuery first, then bootstrap and the plugins after.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-T/tUfKSV1bihCnd+MxKD0Hm1uBBroVYBOYSk1knyvQ9VyZJpc/ALb4P0r6ubwVPSGB2GvjeoMAJJImBG12TiaQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure never to load the same library twice...

Also, you used `jQuery.noConflict()` for some reason... And defined the jQuery variable a `$j`... But continued using `$` after.

---

So here is your code working in a snippet:

```js
jQuery.browser = {};
(function () {
  jQuery.browser.msie = false;
  jQuery.browser.version = 0;
  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)\./)) {
    jQuery.browser.msie = true;
    jQuery.browser.version = RegExp.$1;
  }
})();
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
  $j("#datepickerstart").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
  });
  var date = new Date();
  var val =
    date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate();
  $j(".labelDate").text(val);
  //$("#datepicker").val(val);
  //alert("test");
  $j("#datatable").DataTable();
  $j("#admindatatable").DataTable();
  $j("#empdatatable").DataTable();
  $j(".checkin").click(function () {
    var clock = $j("#clock").text();
    var data = $j("#userClock").val(clock);
  });
  $j(".selectemp").click(function () {
    // $('#admindatatable').css("display","none");
  });
  $j(".btntest").click(function () {
    //$('#admindatatable').css("display","block");
  });
  $j("#emplist tr").click(function () {
    $j(this).toggleClass("selected");
  });
  var selectedrow;
  $j("#emplist tr").click(function (e) {
    $j("#emplist tr").removeClass("selected");
    $j(this).addClass("selected");
    selectedrow = $(this);
  });
  $j(".btnselect").click(function () {
    var td = selectedrow.children("td");
    var id = td.eq(0).text();
    var name = td.eq(1).text();
    var pos = td.eq(2).text();
    $j("#name").val(name);
    $j("#position").val(pos);
    $j("#empid").val(id);
    $j("#exampleModalLong").modal().hide();
    $j("body").removeClass("modal-open");
    $j(".modal-backdrop").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" style="background-color:#007bff;">
          <h3 class="card-title" style=" color:white;">

            Attendance</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- /.card-header -->
        <div class="card-body">

          <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
          <div class="info">
            <div class="row">

              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empid" name="name" style="display:none;">

              <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="name">Position</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="position" name="position">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="name"></label>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary selectemp" style="margin-top:30px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">Select Employee</button>

              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="name">Date Start</label>
                <input class="date form-control" type="text" id="datepickerstart" name="datepickerstart">

              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="btnbrowse">

            </div>

            <table class="table table-striped" id="admindatatable" style="margin:0 auto;">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <!--<th style="text-align : center;">ID</th>-->
                  <th style="text-align : center;">Name</th>
                  <th style="text-align : center;">Check In</th>
                  <th style="text-align : center;">Check Out</th>
                  <th style="text-align : center;">Note</th>
                  <th style="text-align : center;">Total</th>
                  <th style="text-align : center;">Date</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <!--<td style="text-align : center;" class="id"></td>-->
                  <td style="text-align : center;" class="id"></td>
                  <td style="text-align : center;" class="checkin"></td>
                  <td style="text-align : center;" class="checkout"></td>
                  <td style="text-align : center;" class="note"></td>
                  <td style="text-align : center;" class="note"></td>
                  <td style="text-align : center;" class="date"></td>
                </tr>

              </tbody>
            </table>

          </div>

          <!-- /.card-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
        <!-- /.card -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="confirmModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Check In</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Are you sure you want to Check In?
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btnConfirmCheckIN">Yes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="confirmModalCheckOut" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Check Out</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Are you sure you want to Check Out?
        </div>-
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btnConfirmCheckOut">Yes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Employee</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">

            <table class="table" id="emplist" style="margin:0 auto;">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th style="display:none;">Position</th>

                </tr>
              </thead>
              @foreach ($infos as $info)
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="id">{{ $info->id}}</td>
                  <td class="emplistname">{{$info->name}}</td>
                  <td class="emplistname" style="display:none;">{{$info->position}}</td>

                </tr>
                @endforeach
              </tbody>
            </table>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnselect">Select</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-T/tUfKSV1bihCnd+MxKD0Hm1uBBroVYBOYSk1knyvQ9VyZJpc/ALb4P0r6ubwVPSGB2GvjeoMAJJImBG12TiaQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

  <script>

  </script>
```